# If I start letting Google generate my app signing key, how do existing customers get app updates?

Tags: android, android-app-signing

So if I already have an Android app in the hands of many customers, and I sign the app myself with an APK, but want to start using Play App Signing and let Google generate the app signing key, won't my current customers be unable to update the app thereafter?  My understanding is that updates will only be accepted on the mobile device if the app signing cert is the same for the update as for the already-installed app.  If I start using Play App Signing *and* let Google generate the (new) app signing key, obviously the cert will change.  Have I got this right?  How best to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

So what happens is you sign the app with key A.  Google can recognize its you from that key.  Google will generate key B, save it, and resign your app with B.  Then it will put that version available for download.

When you later update the app, it will see key A, verify the app, and resign it with key B, the same key it generated last time.  So it will have the same signature and will be accepted by the mobile devices as an update.

So updates work.  You are allowing Google to purposely man in the middle you and you have the risk that Google will decide to alter your app before release.  But most people find that an acceptable risk (they have no real reason to do it and a lot of reasons not to).

Comment: But what if I am already using app signing key C and not yet using Play App Signing.  Mobile device sees key C.  Then I switch to Play App Signing and mobile device sees key B for update?

Comment: If you already have the app out and do not use Google Play Signing, I do not recommend switching to it.  Doing so will break updates for your existing users, unless they uninstall and reinstall.  This feature should only be used for new apps.  Or old apps that lost their signing key and have to break their users anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide Google with the key you wish them to sign the APKs with. You don't have to let Google generate a new key. Make sure to open the advanced options when enrolling and not use the default option for this feature, then follow the instructions.